# How can i connect a Home Cinema System as speakers on PC?

Tags: audio, speakers

I have an [LG Home Cinema System](http://www.lg.com/uk/home-cinema-systems/lg-HT303SU-home-cinema-system) and I want to use it as my PC's speakers. It has a red socket and a white socket that connect to a normal jack output like a headphone to my PC's MOBO ([Asus Z97-K](https://www.asus.com/uk/Motherboards/Z97K/overview/)). It gets recognised as 2 speakers, although the subwoofer works too. How can I use all of the speakers with the PC ?

EDIT: This is how the cable looks on one side
[image: cable]

Comment: What motherboard/sound card have you got?

Comment: The cable is connected to my MOBO (Asus Z97-K)

Comment: Changed the link. Should work now.

Comment: Looking at the back plate of your mobo it appears to only support stereo.

Comment: So I can't play the same sound through all 4 speakers because my MOBO doesn't support 5.1 surround ?

Comment: I think so but I'm not an audio expert.

Comment: Well my MOBO has that blue jack which i don't know what is it used for, so yeah.

Comment: The blue one is stereo audio in. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_card#Color_codes

Comment: So if I use a father-father aux cable i can record let's say, music from my phone or a piano or something ?

Comment: With the correct software, yes. A dedicated sound card might be a better option for that though.

Comment: Well I won't need a soundcard any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

The red and white sockets will be for left and right channels of a stereo signal.  The home cinema should take those signals and redirect the low bass content to the subwoofer, and the remainder of it to the front left and front right of the remaining speakers.  To get that remainder to come out of centre and rear speakers is not necessarily possible.  The home cinema might do an "up mix" or a "Dolby surround" decoding, if you select the right mode, but that will almost certainly not drive all the speakers equally.

For more on "bass management" take a look at annex 7 of Recommendation ITU-R  BS.775 (available for free from the ITU web site).

Comment: So is there a way to make the sound go through all speakers by setting something on the PC or do I need another type of cable ?

Comment: Neither - this type of consumer-level DVD player usually doesn't have the necessary decoders to be able to handle anything other than stereo from an external source. The red/white inputs are stereo; as @Andrew says, it's capable of pushing that through the crossover [possibly right at the analog output] so you will get the sub functioning + the front left/right pair, but it has no decoder for 5.1 other than directly from a DVD.